# What is the conceptual meaning of featureMember in GML?

Tags: gml

In GML there is this tag:

```
<gml:featureMember>
```

I am looking for the conceptual meaning of it, but i only find syntax explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Informally, its a single "entity" that is modelled in the data - like a row in a database or shapefile.

For example in this segment, each `featureMember` is an airport:

```
 <gml:featureMember>
    <airports fid="0">
      <NAME>Bigfork Municipal Airport</NAME>
      <LAT>     47.7789</LAT>
      <LON>    -93.6500</LON>
      <ELEVATION>   1343.0000</ELEVATION>
      <QUADNAME>Effie</QUADNAME>
      <ogr:geometryProperty><gml:Point><gml:coordinates>451306,5291930</gml:coordinates
></gml:Point></ogr:geometryProperty>
    </airports>
  </gml:featureMember>
  <gml:featureMember>
    <airports fid="1">
      <NAME>Bolduc Seaplane Base</NAME>
      <LAT>     47.5975</LAT>
      <LON>    -93.4106</LON>
      <ELEVATION>   1325.0000</ELEVATION>
      <QUADNAME>Balsam Lake</QUADNAME>
      <ogr:geometryProperty><gml:Point><gml:coordinates>469137,5271647</gml:coordinates
></gml:Point></ogr:geometryProperty>
    </airports>
  </gml:featureMember>
```

Note that not all valid GML files will contain `featureMember` tags, because GML schemas may define other tags to contain their features. For example, `cityGML` has a `cityObject` tag.